# i need to write a method using recursion without any use of loops from 1 to max with non descending way

Tags: java, recursion, methods, backtracking

method howManySort(int length,int max) , length declares the length of the array and max declares the maximum number.

- for example if length=3 and max=2 there are 4 ways to sort the numbers from 1 to 2(include) in a non descending way

1. (1,1,1)
2. (1,1,2)
3. (1,2,2)
4. (2,2,2)

- another example is if length=2 and max=3 there are 6 ways to sort the number from 1 to 3(include) in a non descending way

1. (1,1)
2. (1,2)
3. (1,3)
4. (2,2)
5. (2,3)
6. (3,3)

the method must not return or print the array it must return the number of ways that we can sort the array, we can't use any mathematical formula or loops just recursion. please explain the solution

i tried this:

```
public int howManySort(int length,int max){
 return howManySort(length,max,1);
}

private int howManySort(int length,int max){
if(i>max){
 return 0;
}
if(length==0){
 return 1+howManySort(length,max,i+1);
}
return howManySort(length-1,max,i);
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to declare the same method `int howManySort(int length,int max)` twice, once as private and once public? And what is `howManySorted(n,max,1)` supposed to call? I don't see any method with that name.

Comment: First work on fixing your compilation errors. Then you can focus on problems with the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended the private method with 3 parameters where the 3rd one (=i) indicates the minimum.
I understood your intention but you don't need it (see below).

You were almost there:

- If either the maximum or the length is less then 1, then the result is 0
- If the maximum equals 1 then there's a single way, independently of the length
- If the length equals 1 then the number of ways equals the maximum

In all other cases the number of ways is determined as follows:
Just to explain, consider length=max=3.
The possible 10 ways are

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 3 3
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 3 3
3 3 3
```

The first 6 report the number of ways for an array with length minus 1 and the same maximum. Just forget the first column being always 1.
The remaining 4 report the number of ways for an array with the same length and maximum minus 1.
The latter because

```
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 3 3
3 3 3
```

in fact equals

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 2
2 2 2
```

I would therefore implement the method as follows:

```
public int howManySort(int length,
                       int max)
{
  if ((length < 1) || (max < 1))
    return (0);
  else if (max == 1)
    return (1);
  else if (length == 1)
    return (max);
  else
    return (howManySort(length - 1, max) + howManySort(length, max - 1));
}
```